# How to make child span collapse with parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, parent-child, transition

I am teaching myself about animations using simple rectangles and I have so far managed a bit of progress with this simple project:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test slider</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span class="rect">
            <span class="otherrect"></span>
        </span>    
        <p id="button"> click here </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.rect{
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: blue;

    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;   
}

.otherrect {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: red;
}

.closed {
    height: 0;
    background-color: white; 
}

#button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-right: 500px;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").click(function(){

        if ($( ".rect" ).hasClass( "closed" )){

            $(".rect").removeClass("closed");

        } else {

        $(".rect").addClass("closed");  
    }

    });
});
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

So, what I was aiming at, was that the red rectangle (class: otherrect) should also collapse and fade like its parent rectangle. How can I do this without using javascript and preferably not having to use the display property. Thanks for your time. P

---------------------------------EDIT AFTER RECEIVING ANSWERS-----------------------------------

Thank you all for your answers. These are all good in one way or another, but I guess I sould have mentioned that the red rectangle is going to be a video in the finished project so I need it to be a child of the other element because if the class that collapses it is applied to it directly, it affects the way it looks. Please refer to this other question to see a gif of what I mean:
[slideDown() function behaving oddly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267584/slidedown-function-behaving-oddly)

Comment: note: your whole if() could be replaced with a simple `$('.rect').toggleClass('closed')`

Comment: Try not to change the question after you already have answers.  You can make answers that solve the original question invalid.

Comment: Ok sorry i didn't know I'll ask a new question

Comment: @Paul it's kind of too late now :)

Comment: true! since we are on the subject, is there any way to do the animation that I want. i don't want to apply the class to my child element, instead I want it to be affected by the transition that is happening to its parent. Is this wishful thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your span class or add one like this :

```
    <span class="rect">
        <span class="otherrect rect"></span>
    </span>
```

Comment: minor issue: If this is done you would need to be careful about modifying the stylesheet since your display is now dependent on the order the styles are defined.

Comment: yeah i should have spoke about this too, thanks for the improvement !

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` in the `.rect {` class and your good. :)

Comment: This doesn't really collapse and fade the "otherrect" like it's parent

Answer (score 0):

Move the animation settings into a 3rd class ("anim"), give both `span` elements that class as well and add the "closed" class to any element with the "anim" class in your onclick.

Note: This uses the same amount of JavaScript as your question, which I assume is ok (but technically doesn't meet the "without using javascript" requirement)

(thx to Mark B for the onclick)

EDIT: Added a video.  The animation is a little hokey, sorry :(

```js
$(function(){
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $('.anim').toggleClass('closed')
    });
});
```

```css
.rect{
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.anim {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.otherrect {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: red;
}

.closed {
    height: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

video {all:inherit}

#button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-right: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <span class="rect anim">
        <span class="otherrect anim"><video class="anim" controls>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
</video></span>
    </span>
    <p id="button"> click here </p>
</body>
```